# Discrepancy between C and Python when evaluating a boolean expression

Tags: python, operator-precedence

Considering the code:

```
print( 1==2<3, (1==2)<3, 1==(2<3) )
False True True
```

I don't understand why the first expression `1==2<3` is evaluated to False. Precedence of `<`and `==` is the same and I guessed that in such a case expression is evaluated from left to right. But obviously, this is not the case.

Note that an equivalent C program evaluates all the three expressions to True.

Comment: Thanks, I'm impressed you were able to find the duplicate from 7 years ago in less than a minute.

Comment: It becomes a habit if you see this kind of question often enough.